# Admin Scripts enqueue codes seems ok but not working

Tags: wp-admin

I am trying to load style sheet and scripts to my admin backend in wordpress.I have coded the following but not working anyway.What should be changed in coding.
I think everything is okay but still not loading styles and scripts.And also these files exists in those directory.

### Below is my code

```
define('MYPLUGIN_BASENAME',     plugin_basename( __FILE__ ));

define('MYPLUGIN_ROOT_FILE',    __FILE__);

define('MYPLUGIN_URL',      plugin_dir_url(MYPLUGIN_ROOT_FILE));

define('MYPLUGIN_CSS_URL',  MYPLUGIN_URL . 'assets/css');

define('MYPLUGIN_JS_URL',   MYPLUGIN_URL . 'assets/js');

add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'backEndAssets');
function backEndAssets(){
    wp_enqueue_style( 
        'mypluginadmincss', 
        MYPLUGIN_CSS_URL . '/admin-styles.css', 
        array( '' ), 
        'all' 
    );
    wp_enqueue_script( 
        'mypluginadminjs', 
        MYPLUGIN_JS_URL . '/admin-scripts.js', 
        array( '' ),
        false 
    );
}
```

Comment: They are not loaded or they are not working? Check the source code and the URL of each asset. Your code seems ok, do the checks.

Answer (score -1):

Please, try the following code,

```
namespace YOUR_PLUGIN;
function backEndAssets() {
    wp_enqueue_style('MYPLUGIN_CSS_URL', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'assets/css/admin-styles.css');
    wp_enqueue_script('MYPLUGIN_JS_URL', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'assets/js/admin-scripts.js', array('jquery', 'media-upload'), '1.0.0', true);
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', __NAMESPACE__ . '\backEndAssets' );
```

As you are not creating object inside plugin and want to load script then you must define namespace at the begging and define the plugin folder name and add this namesapce before function as I did. Either Wordpress didn't recognise the function.